# Sensenet: Validate "compulsory" fields when the file is uploaded to a document library

Tags: sensenet

I have a document library that has some fields as compulsory but when I upload them sensenet does not required the fill of that fields.

This is working only on the edit function

Answer (score 1):

The problem with this feature is that on the built-in UI you **cannot actually fill any fields** when you upload a document. So if you had *any* compulsory fields (and we validated them) you would not be able to upload documents *at all*, the system would deny that.

Currently I do not know an out-of-the-box solution for this, you would have to create a custom upload UI (of course using the built-in simple upload functionality) that makes sure the user fills the compulsory fields before uploading the doc.

If you think this is something we should look into, please create an [issue on github](https://github.com/SenseNet/sensenet/issues).